# Enviar String do Arduino para o C# via Serial

Tags: c#, string, arduino, serial

Estou precisando enviar Strings do Arduino para o C# em tempo real via comunicação Serial.

No código do arduino estou utilizando o seguinte para enviar:

```
if (Serial.available()) //se byte pronto para leitura
{
   switch(Serial.read())      //verifica qual caracter recebido
   {
      case 'T':
          Serial.print("STATUS");
      break:
   }
}
```

E no C# para receber a string:

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   RxString = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
   Console.WriteLine(RxString);
}
```

SAÍDA:

ST

ATUS

ST

ATUS

STAT

US

ST

ATUS

ST

ATUS

STAT

US

S

Porém, estou recebendo a String quebrada. O que estou deixando de fazer? Tem uma forma melhor de fazer isso?

Comment: Só com este trecho não dá para saber. Adicione partes relevantes do código.

Comment: Se possível mostre a saída, mostrando o problema e mostre melhor o seu código, senão fica complicado ajudar.

Comment: Atualizei aí pessoal. Não tem muita coisa no código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso é o esperado de uma comunicação serial.

Não existe separação entre os dados enviados e nem garantia que eles cheguem todo de uma vez.

Seguindo o seu exemplo, não existe garantia de que uma única chamada ao `Serial.print` não possa chegar em diversas partes no seu programa em C#, assim como pode acontecer de diversas chamadas consecutivas ao `Serial.print` feitas em um período muito curto cheguem todas juntas de uma vez só no seu programa em C#.

Então basicamente cabe a você criar uma forma de tratar os dados corretamente, não só de saber se chegou os dados inteiro como também de separar caso cheguem dados de mais de uma mensagem ao mesmo tempo.

Eu diria que o mais básico que se pode ter se tratando de um protocolo baseado em textos seria o uso de um delimitador, por exemplo no arduino você marcaria o final da mensagem com algum caractere que tem certeza que nunca vai ser usado, como por exemplo um `#`

```
Serial.print("STATUS#");
```

Então no C# você precisa fazer duas coisas, primeiro de tudo você vai precisar criar um buffer para guardar os dados, pois pode chegar menos dados que o necessário, então tudo que chegar você adiciona nesse buffer, depois de adicionado os dados no buffer você verifica se tem dados suficientes para tratar, caso tenha então você começa a processar o buffer e só para quando ver que o buffer está vazio ou que os dados nele não são o suficiente para se processar.

```
//buffer usado para guardar as mensagens, iniciado como uma string vazia
string buffer = "";

private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    //sempre recebe os dados adicionando no final do buffer
    buffer += serialPort1.ReadExisting();
    //depois de receber os dados verifica se possui uma mensagem inteira nele
    //devemos fazer isso em um loop pois pode acontecer de chegar mais de uma
    //mensagem ao mesmo tempo
    int idx;
    while((idx = buffer.IndeOf('#')) >= 0)
    {
        //separamos a primeira mensagem do buffer sem o delimitador
        string mensagem = buffer.Substring(0, idx);
        //tratamos ela da forma que for necessário
        Console.WriteLine(mensagem);
        //por fim removemos ela do buffer
        buffer = buffer.Substring(idx + 1);
    }
}
```

Lembrando que qualquer informação não processada por ser insuficiente ficou no buffer, caso a comunicação por algum motivo seja interrompida e precise ser iniciada novamente você pode precisar limpar este buffer.

Tem que sempre levar em conta também que comunicação serial pode não ser muito confiável, já tive um caso em que a comunicação com um aparelho de tempos em tempo perdia um byte, era uma limitação do hardware do aparelho e não tinha o que fazer, eu tive que levar isso em consideração e ignorar quando eu detectava uma mensagem que estava incompleta.

Esta mesma lógica vale praticamente para qualquer tipo de comunicação serial, seja uma porta serial, TCP/IP ou Bluetooth usando RFCOMM por exemplo.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela instrução Leandro, nota 10! Vou colocar em prática e posto o resultado. Estou fazendo uma aplicação para monitorar vários sensores em tempo real e ao mesmo tempo. Após essa comunicação por porta COM, quero fazer por TCP/IP ou UDP tbm.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado Leandro.

Comment: Leandro boa noite.
Tive um problema similar com um projeto de TCC e consegui resolver, uma parte do problema,com a solução que você forneceu.Muito obrigado.